# 500 internal server error when doing ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble investigating an 500 Internal Server Error I get when trying to do an AJAX request ( I'm doing a "PUT" / "GET" ) on my server.

Locally it runs without any issues and it responds, but after I uploaded the content on the server it doesn't, as if the file / folder wouldn't be there.

The [host](http://barbershoppen.rolandgroza.me/) is running on Apache with PHP at least version 5.3.0 since I last checked. I get the error when trying to use the footer newsletter subscribe.

My index file which is requested when doing the AJAX looks like the following :

```
<?php

/*
 * Import PHPMailer Class
*/

require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");


/*
 * Decode JSON Data
*/

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);


/*
 * Check Valid Email Address
*/

if (!filter_var($request["Email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    echo json_encode([
        "error" => true,
        "message"=> "You must enter a valid email address"
    ]);

    return false;
};


/*
 * Instantiate PHPMailer Class
*/

$mailer = new PHPMailer();


/*
 * Set Reply Settings
*/

$reply_email        = "no-reply@barbershoppen.dk";
$reply_name         = "Barber Shoppen";


/*
 * Specific PHPMailer Settings
*/

$mailer->IsSMTP();                                  /* SMTP Usage */
$mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;                         /* SMTP Authentication */
$mailer->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                        /* Sets Servier Prefix */
$mailer->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";             /* SMTP Server */
$mailer->Port       = 465;                          /* SMTP Port */

$mailer->Username   = "rolandeveloper@gmail.com";   /* SMTP Account Username */
$mailer->Password   = "333333333";           /* SMTP Account Password */


/*
 * Email Settings
*/

$mailer->SetFrom($reply_email, $reply_name);
$mailer->AddReplyTo($reply_email, $reply_name);
$mailer->AddAddress($request["Email"]);

$mailer->Subject    = "Barber Shoppen [ Confirmation Email ]";
$mailer->Body       = "You have successfully subscribed to our newsletter";

$mailer->isHTML(true);


/*
 * Send Email
*/

if($mailer->Send()) {

    echo json_encode([
        "error" => false,
        "message"=> "You have successfully subscribed"
    ]);

} else {

    echo json_encode([
        "error" => true,
        "message"=> $mailer->ErrorInfo
    ]);

};
?>
```

I would appreciate some help or some pointers in which directions I should head and fix this error.

Comment: You did not just post your gmail account data in here did you? Hopefully the bad guys wont steal your account before you EDIT the question ...

Comment: Is there an error in the server logs?  "500 Internal Server Error" implies that there is.

Comment: as I think you now know the internal error is because of setting error reporting to off. so please run `ini_set('error_reporting','on');` to to see the exact error.

Comment: yeah ... it's a dev account .... a lot of people have it, but I removed the pass anyway :)

Comment: Check the apache error log: `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to pass in a PHP-style array instead of a javascript-style array into json_encode:

```
if (!filter_var($request["Email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        "error" => true,
        "message"=> "You must enter a valid email address"
    ));

    return false;
};
```

And:

```
if($mailer->Send()) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        "error" => false,
        "message"=> "You have successfully subscribed"
    ));

} else {

    echo json_encode(array(
        "error" => true,
        "message"=> $mailer->ErrorInfo
    ));

};
```

Comment: `echo json_encode([
        "error" => true,
        "message"=> "You must enter a valid email address"
    ]);` would work in php 5.4 with the array short syntax but not in 5.3 !

Comment: I didn't realize that it was added to 5.4, though I like the backwards-compatible style anyway. :-)

Comment: that was it .... but it's strange that I get a 500 and no description, would have been nice to get a small description telling me that I'm stupid and I'm not using the right syntax

Comment: Always check the error log. When the browser throws 500, it doesn't always provide any other info, depending on the error_level. It's usually in the log, though.

Comment: I'll have to enable the error reporting, but I'm having a hard time getting around Plesk ...